# Buscador con ng-repeat en AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo un buscador muy sencillo en mi aplicación web con AngularJS, así de simple:

```html
<input type="search" id="search" maxlength=26 placeholder="Filtrar noticias..." ng-model="search.title">

<li ng-repeat="item in itemData | orderBy:'-order' | filter:search as results"></li>

<span ng-if="results.length==0">No hay resultados...</span>
```

Al escribir en el input automáticamente se van filtrando los items por títulos, cómo puedo hacer para que solo los filtre al presionar enter en la pc o en dispositivos mobiles por ejemplo al presionar el botón de búsqueda en el teclado y que se queden los elementos filtrador aunque borre lo que escribí? Les agradecería mucho la ayuda, por el momento no se mucho de JavaScript y AngularJS.

Actualmente estoy utilizando AngularJS 1.5.7

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar las [opciones](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) de `ng-model`

```
<input type="search" id="search" maxlength=26 
           placeholder="Filtrar noticias..." ng-model="search.title" 
           ng-model-options="{updateOn : 'change blur'}">
```

En este caso cambiando cuales eventos (del elemento input) desencadenan la búsqueda.

Si quieres que se actualize unicamente cuando presionas la tecla enter, creo que lo siguiente deberia hacer el truco.

```
<input type="search" id="search" maxlength=26 
           placeholder="Filtrar noticias..." ng-model="searchAux" 
           ng-keyup="$event.keyCode === 13 && search.title = searchAux">
```

Si prefieres sacarlo del markup y moverlo al contexto...

```
$scope.doKeyUp= function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    $scope.search.title = $scope.searchAux
  }
}
```

Siendo el markup:

```
<input type="search" id="search" maxlength=26 
           placeholder="Filtrar noticias..." ng-model="searchAux" 
           ng-keyup="doKeyUp($event)">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. Al agregar el **ng-model-options="{updateOn : 'change blur'}"** me funciona correctamente pero el filtrado también se activa al dar clic en cualquier lugar fuera del **input** sabes cómo evitarlo?

Comment: @AdrianoJosué y que quieres que suceda? Que se borre el contenido?

Comment: No, solamente quiero que el contenido se filtre si presiono **enter** nada más y con el **ng-model-options="{updateOn : 'change blur'}"** también se filtra si doy clic en cualquier lugar fuera del **input**.

Comment: @rnd Tu respuesta está bien. Sólo reemplaza `ng-model-options="{updateOn : 'change blur'}"` por `ng-model-options="{updateOn : 'change'}"` y funcionará como lo pide el OP.

Comment: @devconcept con **change** sigue funcionando igual pero por alguna razón si coloco por ejemplo **search o cualquier otra palabra** funciona correctamente cómo yo quiero, que es que filtre los elementos solo al presionar enter. es correcto implementarlo así ?

Comment: @AdrianoJosué he editado la respuesta, me demore pues estaba de viaje. espero que te ayude saludos!

Comment: @rnd Gracias de tomar la molestia de ayudarme. Eh utilizado está forma **ng-keyup="$event.keyCode === 13 && search.title = searchAux"** y al presionar enter no sucede nada, tendrás alguna idea de por que sucederá?

Comment: @AdrianoJosué dame unas horas, estoy viajando

Comment: @rnd Ok, muchas gracias.